# Is there a tool to measure Java/Eclipse memory and garbage collector performance?

Tags: java, performance, eclipse, memory-leaks

I do QA for a product performed with plugins over Eclipse and there are automatic tests written with SWTBot. Sometimes on some CI runs the delays are not enough, although they run OK locally. But occasionally I run into a number of out of memory errors and I suspect there might be some memory issues, with the garbage collector messing things on top trying to release memory.

Is there a tool (Eclipse plugin?) to measure Java/Eclipse memory and garbage collector usage/performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.mat):

> The Memory Analyzer provides a general purpose toolkit to analyze Java heap dumps. Besides heap walking and fast calculation of retained sizes, the Eclipse tool reports leak suspects and memory consumption anti-patterns. The main area of application are Out Of Memory Errors and high memory consumption.

The project is open source, actively maintained (supported by SAP as well as IBM), and offers a comprehensive documentation.